# If $\int_X f\varphi d\mu=0$ then $f$ is constant almost every where.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \cal M, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Suppose $f\in L^1(X,\cal M, \mu)$ such that for any $\varphi \in L^{\infty}(X,\cal M, \mu)$ that $\int_X \varphi d\mu=0$, we have $\int_X f\varphi  d\mu=0$. How can I show $f=constant$ almost every where on X.

Comment: Take any $g\in L^{\infty}$ and let $\varphi=g-\frac 1 {\mu (X)} \int gd\mu$. Conclude that $f=\frac 1 {\mu (X)} \int fd\mu$ a.e.

Comment: How can I get the conclusion?

Comment: $f=c$ a.e. is equivalent to $\int (f-c)g=0$ for all $f \in L^{\infty}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm typo in your last comment. You meant to say "...for all $g\in L^{\infty}$".

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thanks! @drhab

Comment: @geetha290krm  Thanks for your comments. Can we extend the result to this "Suppose $f,g \in L^1$" such that for any $\varphi\in L^{\infty}$ that $\int_X g\varphi d \mu=0$ we have $\int_X f \varphi d \mu=0$. Is this implies that there exists a constant $c$ s.t $f=c g$ a.e on $X$.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: @geetha290krm Keep in your mind that for any $\phi \in L^{\infty}$ the identity  $\int_X g\phi=0$ may not hold. is the result still true? If yes how can I prove it?

Comment: I have given a defintion of $\phi$ in terms of $g$. Apply the hypotthesis to this $\phi$ and compute $\int f\varphi$.